# Logout and reset UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm aware that there are some questions out there that are similar to this question, however, a lot of them are in Objective C and I haven't been able to find a really applicable solution yet that works.

The main problem I am having is that when I log out of one account in my app, then log into another, the tab bar is not reset, and it displays the previously signed in users data. In other words, I need a way to "reset" the app back to the state it was in before any user had signed in.

I have tried to achieve this by writing a function inside App Delegate (setupTabBarController) and calling it when the user logs out, but no such luck yet.

This is what I have so far:

Logout code:

```
@objc func handleSignOutButtonTapped() {
    let signOutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: .destructive) { (action) in
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            let welcomeControl = WelcomeController()
            let welcomeNavCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeControl)
            self.present(welcomeNavCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let err {
            print("Failed to sign out with error", err)
            Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Sign Out Error", message: err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .actionSheet, title: nil, message: nil, actions: [signOutAction, cancelAction]) {
    }
    let delegate = AppDelegate()
    delegate.setupTabBarController()
}
```

Part of my App Delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    setupTabBarController()
    return true
}

func setupTabBarController() {
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let vc = MainTabBarController()
    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```

Sign in code:

```
 @objc func handleNormalLogin() {
    hud.textLabel.text = "Signing In..."
    hud.show(in: view, animated: true)
    //TODO
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error signing in: \(error)")
            return
        }
        //sucessfully signed in
        self.hud.dismiss(animated: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated, I have been stuck on this for a few hours now and I really want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Cheers

Comment: I think you are having more than 1 problem here. But first, I think you should show code for sign in method and after that I will give you my answer

Comment: @trungduc will add now

Comment: I have added my answer. You can check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**

- When you write `let delegate = AppDelegate()`. It means that you create a new `AppDelegate`. Instead of using current `AppDelegate`, you use another `AppDelegate`. That's why `setupTabBarController` method doesn't affects anything.
- Calling `setupTabBarController` at the end of `handleSignOutButtonTapped` isn't a good idea. Because it will replace current `rootViewController` with `UINavigation` of `MainTabBarController`.

**Answer**

- Use `self.tabBarController?` instead of `self` to present `welcomeNavCon`.
- Don't call `setupTabBarController` at the end of `handleSignOutButtonTapped` method.
- Recreate and set new `viewControllers` for `MainTabBarController`.

**Code**

```
@objc func handleSignOutButtonTapped() {
  let signOutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: .destructive) { (action) in
    do {
      try Auth.auth().signOut()
      let welcomeControl = WelcomeController()
      let welcomeNavCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeControl)
      self.tabBarController?.present(welcomeNavCon, animated: true) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
        appDelegate.resetTabBarController();
      };
    } catch let err {
      print("Failed to sign out with error", err)
      Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Sign Out Error", message: err.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
  let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
  Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .actionSheet, title: nil, message: nil, actions: [signOutAction, cancelAction]) {
  }
}
```

---

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  var tabBarController : UITabBarController?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    setupTabBarController()
    return true
  }

  func setupTabBarController() {
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let vc = MainTabBarController()
    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    window?.rootViewController = controller
  }

  func resetTabBarController() -> Void {
    let viewControllerAtIndex1 = ...
    let viewControllerAtIndex2 = ...
    let viewControllerAtIndex3 = ...

    tabBarController?.viewControllers = [viewControllerAtIndex1, viewControllerAtIndex2, viewControllerAtIndex3];
  }

}
```

Comment: What if my Tab bar consist of Navigation controllers